# sql query to find table_name and count(table_name) in a schema

Tags: sql, oracle

sql query to find `table_name` and `count(table_name)` in a schema:

Example:

I get the table_name from this query:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES
```

and count(table_name) from

```
select count(*) from employee
select count(*) from dept
select count(*) from subjects
```

now i want to get the result like this:

```
table_name     count(table_name)
Employee        100
dept            21
subjects        56
```

Comment: why does not accept any answer in your questions?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
select
       table_name,
       to_number(
         extractvalue(
           xmltype(
             dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c ' ||
                                ' from '||owner||'.'||table_name))
           ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count
   from all_tables
  where table_name In ( 
  SELECT table_name from user_tables )
```

OR Using Join

```
select
       a.table_name,
       to_number(
         extractvalue(
           xmltype(
             dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c ' ||
                                ' from '||owner||'.'||a.table_name))
           ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count
   from all_tables a JOIN user_tables u ON
  a.table_name=u.table_name  AND a.owner = user
```

Comment: +1 Nice. But instead of using `IN` for the table_name, I'd suggest using a JOIN - otherwise, you might get additional rows if a table with the same name exists in different schemas.

Comment: The second version still has the same problem. You need to add `AND a.owner = user' to your JOIN condition, or you can simply use user_tables instead of all_tables.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typical use case for a simple UNION ALL:

```
select 
  'Employee' table_name,
  count(*) from employee 
union all
select 
  'dept' table_name,
  count(*) from dept 
union all
select 
  'subjects' table_name,
  count(*) from subjects
```

If you want to automate this, you can iterate over `USER_TABLES`:

```
declare
  l_cnt pls_integer;
begin
  for cur in (select table_name from user_tables order by table_name)
  loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from ' || cur.table_name into l_cnt;
    dbms_output.put_line(cur.table_name || ' ' || l_cnt);
  end loop;
end;
```

Instead of simply printing the result, you can also build a SQL statement dynamically and use that afterwards:

```
declare
  l_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
  for cur in (select table_name from user_tables order by table_name)
  loop
    l_sql := l_sql || ' select ' || cur.table_name || ' as table_name, count(*) as cnt from ' || cur.table_name || ' union all';
  end loop;
  -- remove trailing UNION ALL
  l_sql := regexp_replace(l_sql, 'union all$', '');
  dbms_output.put_line(l_sql);
end;
```

Comment: This is the idea. Now I think OP's doesn't want to hard code the table names, so some dynamic Sql should be used.

Comment: @frank : The schema has 200 tables and i cant write union for all so i want a gneric way to do this.